# Can I get the email address from a user sign-in with the Twitter framework in iOS 5+?

Tags: objective-c, twitter, ios5, social-networking

I have a requirement in my app to sign up with Twitter, so for a first time user, the server stores (among other things) email, password, first name and last name.

But the only things I can get from the Twitter/social framework is the profile id, username, first name and last name. Is there any alternative for getting the email address, or will I have to change the signup mode in my server's app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that we cant get email address from twitter, so I had to change my signup mode by validation through the twitter login and users profile id. If anybody else has found a workaround please do post your solution. I'll mark that as best answer.